# BootstrapDialog confirm inside another function not working

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-dialog

I use BootstrapDialog  library to display modal dialogs an alert an  confirm messages I use ***BootstrapDialog.confirm*** method in side another function to reuse with some parameters like button text,message text etc .... for that I write bellow code for testing purpose ,but the function not return anything always return *undefined* .

```
 <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<script>
function callconfirm()
{
   // var isConfirmed
     BootstrapDialog.confirm({
            title: 'WARNING',
            message: 'Warning! Drop your banana?',
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
            closable: false, // <-- Default value is false
            draggable: false, // <-- Default value is false
            btnCancelLabel: 'Do not drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'Cancel',
            btnOKLabel: 'Drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'OK',
            btnOKClass: 'btn-warning', // <-- If you didn't specify it, dialog type will be used,
            callback: function(result) {
                // result will be true if button was click, while it will be false if users close the dialog directly.
                if(result) {
                  return true;
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

}

function checkConfirm()
{
    var v=callconfirm();
    console.log(v);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button"  value="click" onclick="checkConfirm()" style="height: 50px;width: 50px" />
</body>
```

Comment: `callconfirm` doesn't return anything, so it's returning `undefined`. Do you want to return the value of  `BootstrapDialog.confirm` instead ?

Comment: yes I want get isConfirmed true or false to proceed next step

Comment: I posted an answer, check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from from [Dante](https://github.com/nakupanda) creator of this plugin I share this bellow which is working fine with extra parameter .

https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/issues/329

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<script>
function callconfirm(cb)
{
    var isConfirmed
     BootstrapDialog.confirm({
            title: 'WARNING',
            message: 'Warning! Drop your banana?',
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
            closable: false, // <-- Default value is false
            draggable: false, // <-- Default value is false
            btnCancelLabel: 'Do not drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'Cancel',
            btnOKLabel: 'Drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'OK',
            btnOKClass: 'btn-warning', // <-- If you didn't specify it, dialog type will be used,
            callback: cb
        });

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button"  value="click" onclick="javascript:callconfirm(console.log)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `BootstrapDialog.confirm` would call the callback on the action. So, it's better if you can do the `console.log` in the callback instead. The function would return immediately and you wouldn't be able to rely on the result value untill the user actually clicks on the OK or Cancel button.

**Working code:**

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<script>
function callconfirm()
{
    var isConfirmed
     BootstrapDialog.confirm({
            title: 'WARNING',
            message: 'Warning! Drop your banana?',
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
            closable: false, // <-- Default value is false
            draggable: false, // <-- Default value is false
            btnCancelLabel: 'Do not drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'Cancel',
            btnOKLabel: 'Drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'OK',
            btnOKClass: 'btn-warning', // <-- If you didn't specify it, dialog type will be used,
            callback: function(result) {
                // result will be true if button was click, while it will be false if users close the dialog directly.
                if(result) {
                  isConfirmed=true;
                   console.log(isConfirmed);
                }else {
                    isConfirmed=false;
                     console.log(isConfirmed);
                }
            }
        });

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button"  value="click" onclick="callconfirm()" style="height: 50px;width: 50px" />
</body>
```

Comment: printing within call back is working ,but if callconfirm() called out side its not return anything ,please check updated code .I want the return in checkConfirm()

Comment: I haven't read the entire documentation, but it seems that the only way to get back the result is to specify the callback. So, you can pass the callback to the method and then evaluate the result.

Comment: please check my updated code in initial post ,where id declare a callback method name cb() and assign to callback and that is called but you said then "you can pass the callback to the method and then evaluate the result." I am not able to figure out this ,can you please give an example ?

Comment: I don't see the variable `id` & `cb` in your code, are you referring to Tareq Code ?

Comment: I am never do like this.so a example is helpful for me to understand the process .

Comment: You can refer to Tareq answer as i do not want to duplicate the code, but basically callback can be any function, so console.log is also a function, which has been passed to the callConfirm method. Does it make sense now ?

Comment: thanks for explanation and also for my misunderstanding . So i need to specify a callback function name as parametar to callconfirm() functon ,should i pass string for function name as parameter?

Comment: Only the function name, but do not invoke the function, so if the function name is function1, it should be passed as `function1` only,

Comment: Hi Agalo ,I am facing another problem .I need to delete some record if call back is true  based on multiple criteria which I want to pass into the callback function  with this code not possible can you please give some idea?

Comment: You can create a  new function encapsulating all the criteria and then call it as a callback, essentially placing all the logic in Callback method.

Comment: A piece of sample is more helpfull

Comment: I suggest you post another question with more details.

Comment: Again, i have not read the entire documentation for BootStrapConfirm, 
 but Callback method of `BootstrapDialog.confirm` wouldn't pass additional information other than result value. So, it is better if you can declare local variables in the function `b1checkConfirm` method and then operate on those values.

Answer (score 0):

Thankx Agalo and Tareq for suggestion and help I post the solution code bellow which may help some one else.

```
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<script>

function callconfirm(cb)
{
   // var isConfirmed
     BootstrapDialog.confirm({
            title: 'WARNING',
            message: 'Warning! Drop your banana?',
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
            closable: false, // <-- Default value is false
            draggable: false, // <-- Default value is false
            btnCancelLabel: 'Do not drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'Cancel',
            btnOKLabel: 'Drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'OK',
            btnOKClass: 'btn-warning', // <-- If you didn't specify it, dialog type will be used,
            callback:cb /*function(result) {
                // result will be true if button was click, while it will be false if users close the dialog directly.
                if(result) {
                  return true;
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
            }*/
        });

}

function b1checkConfirm(result)
{
    //callconfirm();
    console.log("B1 click and result is "+result);
}
function b2checkConfirm(result)
{
    //callconfirm();
    console.log("B2 click and result is "+result);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button"  onclick="callconfirm(b1checkConfirm)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px" >B1</button>
<button type="button"  onclick="callconfirm(b2checkConfirm)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px" >B2</button>
</body>
```